# How to display a file instead of downloading it with react

Tags: html, nrwl-nx, toml, stellar

I use nx to build react apps and deploy it to vercel. I am able to generate `.well-known` folder with `stellar.toml` file inside it and then reference it in `index.html` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    lang="en"
    clasName="h-full">
    <head>
        ...

        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link
            rel="stellar.toml file"
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/.well-known/stellar.toml" />

        ...

    </head>
    <body className="h-full">
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The deployment is successful, but any time I want to display the file when entering {domain}/.well-known/stellar.toml it's prompting me to download it instead of displaying it in the tab.

I am using react-router also in case it's better to do it with react-router. Is there a way to just display it instead of the download prompt?

Comment: Sorry, *what* file are you trying to display instead of download?

Comment: It's stellar.toml file

Comment: And what would you be displaying? Are you trying to have your React app fetch/load this file, or does React have nothing to do with the `head` tag? It's unclear what you are expecting the code to do.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. For example if you enter `https://stellar.org/.well-known/stellar.toml` the .toml file will display the values inside. Similar to .json file

I would like similarly to enter my domain with the route /.well-known/stellar.toml to also display the file values like the above link. However at the moment when I enter that route on my domain it prompts the download of that file instead of displaying the values in it.